# Count a field in database

Tags: mysql, join, laravel-5

I want to count a field name 'leave_policy' depending on the name of 'leave_policy' and I am using joins to do it. My database is like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mliw4.jpg

and I want to show count in applied section. For example if I want to count all "Urgent Leaves" and "Paternal Leaves" seperately I have applied till now.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QR7X.jpg

```
    $join = DB::table('leaves_policy')
        ->join('leaves_policies', 'leaves_policy.leave_policy', '=', 'leaves_policies.title')
        ->join('leaves_requests', 'leaves_policy.requested_by' , '=', 'leaves_requests.requested_by')
        ->select('leaves_policy.*', 'leaves_policies.title', 'leaves_policies.total_no_of_leaves_allowed_per_year',
            'leaves_policies.no_of_months_leaves_valid', 'leaves_policies.max_leaves_per_month', 'leaves_policies.max_con_leaves_per_month',
            'leaves_requests.leave_status', DB::raw('COUNT(leaves_policy.leave_policy) as count'))
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->get();
```

Comment: what do you mean by "count a filed name"?

Comment: if what you want is to count the result from the query
you can use ->count() aggregate

Comment: I want to count ''leave_policy'' depending on the selection of 'leave_policy'. For example if I want to count all "Urgent Leaves" I have applied till now.

Comment: I want to show this count in applied section https://imgur.com/a/dvjuX

Answer (score 1):

For example,

I have a table Leave_table. leave_policy and purpose are the fields.
[image: Table Data]

I am displaying the leave count based on the leave_policy column. i have used the below query to get the count.

select leave_policy,count(leave_policy) from leave_table group by leave_policy

[image: Leave Result]